# jQuery parents not work in print preview function

Tags: javascript, jquery, printing

I need to print preview data using `javascript` and jQuery `click`, `parents` and `find` like this:

HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="print-table">print</a>
<div class="filter-data">
  <div class="product-table">
    <div class="table-product">
      title 1
    </div>
    <div class="table-product">
      title 2
    </div>
    <div class="table-product">
      title 3
    </div>
    <div class="table-product">
      title 4
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
  $("body").on("click", ".print-table", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let parent = $(this)
      .parents(".filter-data")
      .find(".product-table");
    printElem(parent.find(".table-product"));
  });
  function printElem(elem) {
    var element = [];
    var mywindow = window.open("", "PRINT", "height=400,width=600");
    var obj = elem.clone();
    for (i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
      $(obj[i]).find(".exclude-export").remove();
    }
    for (const element of obj) {
      mywindow.document.write(element.outerHTML);
    }
    mywindow.document.close();
    mywindow.focus();
    setTimeout(function() {
      mywindow.print();
      mywindow.close();
    }, 1000);
    return !0;
  }
```

but in action I can see data in print preview.

How do can I fix this error?

[Demo HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/51hzmn3g/)

Comment: In your HTML, `.filter-data` isn't a parent of the `.print-table` `<a>` that has the event handler

Comment: @freedomn-m: oh! ok you right. can I print with `<a>` event handler. without `parents` method?

Comment: If you only have one filter-data then use `let parent = $(".filter-data").find(".product-table");` otherwise `let parent = $(this).next().find(".product-table");` with the HTML provided